# What is the best way to check when a button is loaded (in my scenario)

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to create an extension for Firefox, the goal is to change the style of a button. Nothing very difficult.

However when I run my script it doesn't detect my button, I noticed that the button was created via a parameter contained in an api call so I assumed I had to wait for the site scripts to be loaded but none of the solutions I've found work apart from waiting 2 or 3 seconds with setTimeout.

But I'd still like to know why what I've found doesn't work. And I'm afraid that with a slow connection, setTimeout won't work anyway.

My first code:

```js
const e = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="cta:special-offer"]');
console.info('e found', e);

if (e.length > 0) {
    console.info('target found qnd destroyed, stop observing');
    e[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

The result: `e found NodeList []`
But the button is there.

Then I tried to observe the parent to detect the addition of the button, but idem the target is empty:

```js
/**
 * detect the ul (target) and observe if a child is added, if the child is the button destroy it
 */
function findAndDestroy() {
    console.info('Dom loaded, Script loaded');

    console.info('header', document.getElementsByClassName('header'));

    /*
     * it's seam that the button appear after an api call at 'https://mail.proton.me/api/core/v4/experiments'
     * so I used a mutation and when the ul (parent) is updated I remove the btn if it exists
     */

    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    const target = document.getElementsByClassName('topnav-list');
    console.info('target found', target);

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };

    if (target > 0) {
        const targetNode = target[0];
        console.info('targetNode found', targetNode);

        // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
        const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
            for (const mutation of mutationList) {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList') { // A child node has been added or removed
                    console.info('A child node has been added or removed');
                    removebtn();
                }
            }
        };

        // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
        const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

        // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    }
}

/**
 * remove the btn if found
 */
function removebtn() {
    const e = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="cta:special-offer"]');
    console.info('e found', e);

    if (e.length > 0) {
        console.info('target found qnd destroyed, stop observing');
        e[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

removebtn()
```

Then I tested:

- `window.onload =`
- `document.onreadystatechange =`
- `document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {})`

But now nothing works. Even with a simple `console.log` I have nothing appearing in the console...

```js
document.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    console.log("page is fully loaded");
});

// or 
window.onload = (event) => {
    console.log("page is fully loaded");
};

// or
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        findAndDestroy();
    }
})
```

Comment: [Detect element loaded](https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+extension+detect+element+loaded+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Mutation observer is what you need. You likely implemented it incompletly

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",findAndDestroy)` - does that console.log anything when in your extension? If not, then your extension is not running until too late